# Android Studio xml Preview Window The preview doesn't come up

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface

[Current Android Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmxwI.png)

```
ava.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:369)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I don't know why the above error occurs.

Error corresponding xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/work_out" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sign_up"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/male"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/male" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/female"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/female" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birth"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/birth"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="323dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_id"
                android:layout_width="142dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/ID"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/id_check_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/id_check"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_pw"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_up" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The top part is the error part of the UI preview window in the XML code below.
If you look at the picture, you can't see the UI in the preview window and the screen comes out like that. I can't find a way to solve it.
Thank you for reading it. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/johanesburg" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ImageView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/female"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/female" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/birth"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/birth"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_id"
            android:layout_width="142dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/ID"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id_check_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/id_check"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_pw"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up" />
 </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't fix the problem.